# How many sentences are there (up to tautologies) in a finite langugage $L = \left \{ P_1,...,P_n \right \}$

Tags: combinatorics, logic

I know that there are $2^n$ possible truth evaluations for a langauge $L$ of cardinality $n$

However, how can I count how many sentences are there constructed by the languge up to tautologies?

Is the answer $2^{(2^n)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by *up to tautologies* the fact that you identify two sentences that have the same truth table, then the number you're looking for is indeed $2^{(2^n)}$.

This is because a truth table over $L = \left \{ P_1,…,P_n \right \}$ is just a map from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}$. As $\{0,1\}^n$ has $2^n$ elements, the desired result is effectively $2^{(2^n)}$.